# Use offset and fetch with case in MS SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, offset

I want to use offset conditionally. That is only when my condition satisfies only then rows should be fetched using offset. Otherwise, return the whole data.  But I think the below syntax is wrong. What is the correct approach to do this?

```
DECLARE @page int
set @page = 2

DECLARE @check int
set @check = 2

SELECT * FROM HolonSsoRequest ORDER BY 1 DESC
CASE WHEN @check = 2
THEN
OFFSET @page ROWS FETCH NEXT @page ROWS ONLY;
END
```

Comment: You can't use a `case` expression for flow control. This is well documented in the Remarks section of the [`case` expression documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax you have is all over the place above. Your `END`, for example, is *after* the end of your statement (defined by the statement terminator (`;`)), and you're trying to use a `CASE` **expression** like it's a `Case` (`Switch`) statement. `Case` (`Switch`) statements don't exist in Transact-SQL.

Considering the simplicity of your query, I would personally do something like this, and use a Dynamic Statement:

```
DECLARE @Page int,
        @Check int;
SET @page = 2;
SET @Check = 2;

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX),
        @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10);

SET @SQL = N'SELECT *' + @CRLF +
           N'FROM dbo.HolonSsoRequest' + @CRLF + 
           N'ORDER BY {Column Name} DESC' + --Don't use Ordinal Positions: https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/06/bad-habits-to-kick-order-by-ordinal
           CASE @Check WHEN 2 THEN @CRLF + N'OFFSET @Page ROWS FETCH NEXT @Page ROWS ONLY;' ELSE N';' END;

--PRINT @SQL; --YOur debugging friend

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@Page int', @Page;
```

Comment: How to convert @ Page. This is the sql statement it is printing -> SELECT *
FROM dbo.HolonSsoRequest
OFFSET @ Page ROWS FETCH NEXT @ Page ROWS ONLY;

Comment: What do you mean "convert @ Page", @PrashantYadav ? I don't have any conversions on `@Page` in my statement, and nor do you in your sample query. Why are you trying to `CONVERT` it at all? `OFFSET` expects integer values, which is what `@Page` is.

Comment: @ Page should get value declared above. Currently @ Page is getting printed as it is. And I'm getting error-> SELECT *
FROM dbo.HolonSsoRequest
OFFSET @ Page ROWS FETCH NEXT @  ROWS ONLY;
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near '@ Page'.
Msg 153, Level 15, State 2, Line 4
Invalid usage of the option NEXT in the FETCH statement

Comment: @PrashantYadav near " @ Page"? I don't have `@ Page` in my code, only `@page`.

Comment: @Larun I'm using @ and Page with space as stackoverflow was thinking its username

Comment: Larnu*, @PrashantYadav, and put it in code markup: `@Page`. I cannot replciate this problem: [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=5b36bd681ea46391a8d8af748dc89cb9). This implies you've change the code somewhere and implemented an error.

Comment: `SELECT *
    FROM dbo.HolonSsoRequest

    OFFSET @Page ROWS FETCH NEXT @Page ROWS ONLY;
    Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
    Incorrect syntax near '@Page'.
    Msg 153, Level 15, State 2, Line 4
    Invalid usage of the option NEXT in the FETCH statement.`

Comment: Where is the `ORDER BY` @PrashantYadav ? YOu can't `OFFSET` without an `ORDER BY`. Why did you remove it?

Comment: I didn't know that. Yes, its working now, thanks :)

Comment: @PrashantYadav it makes no sense to be able to `OFFSET` without an `ORDER BY`. How can the RDBMS give you the "next" *x* rows, after "skipping" the first *y*, when it doesn't know where the start from.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use [`IF ... ELSE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/if-else-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

```
DECLARE @page integer;
DECLARE @check integer;

SET @page = 2;
SET @check = 2;

IF @check = 2
BEGIN
  SELECT *
         FROM holonssorequest
         ORDER BY 1 DESC
         OFFSET @page ROWS
         FETCH NEXT @page ROWS ONLY;
END
ELSE
BEGIN
  SELECT *
         FROM holonssorequest
         ORDER BY 1 DESC;
END;
```

Or use two `CASE` expressions, one for the offset and one for the limit that evaluate to 0 or the count of rows in the table respectively if the variable doesn't indicate to limit the results.

```
SELECT *
       FROM holonssorequest
       ORDER BY 1 DESC
       OFFSET CASE
                WHEN @check = 2 THEN
                  @page
                ELSE
                  0
               END ROWS
       FETCH NEXT CASE
                    WHEN @check = 2 THEN
                      @page
                    ELSE
                      (SELECT count(*)
                              FROM holonssorequest)
                  END ROWS ONLY;
```

Comment: This answer actually answered the question asked which was great for me when I got directed here from search.